# remove file:// prefix from DFileManager launch path in Preferred Applications

Tags: command, filepath, xfce

[DFileManager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dfilemanager/) doesn't recognize the `file://` prefix when launched with something like `file:///home/user/Documents/` from things like the Places panel plugin in XFCE, but it does recognise `/home/user/Documents/`

but when configuring the launch command in Preferred Applications, I can't seem to figure out how to remove the prefix
`$ dfm ${"%s"#"file://"}` doesn't work and I can't seem to find any simple documentation or example to explain how to make it work.

what do I have to do that I'm not being made aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to do what I wanted simply from Preferred Applications
so instead I passed it to `dfm.sh "%s"` with these 2 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
/media/user/Programs/dfm/AppRun "${1:7}"
```

it's a garbage solution yes, but it's not like it really needs to be universal, since those first 7 characters will never be anything other than `file://`

Comment: This answer is just a workaround, if it's possible to not use `dfm.sh` and do it straight from Preferred Applications, I'll mark that answer as accepted